# How can I modify the grid parameters from an trained ML model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, parameters, grid-search

I have trained an `xgboost.XGBClassifier` model with `GridSearchCV`, when calling `grid_search_xgb.best_estimator_.get_params()` to obtain the best parameters of that model I get this:

```
{'objective': 'binary:logistic',
 ...
 'missing': nan,
 'monotone_constraints': '()',
 'n_estimators': 1000,
 ...
 }
```

From a plot I did, I know that this model is overfitted. However, if `n_estimators = 123`, then the training and test evaluation metric are very similar (minimum overfitting). Hence, I will train the model again **only replacing the `n_estimators`** with 123 instead of 1000, with this piece of code:

```
optimal_params_grid = grid_search_xgb.best_estimator_.get_params()
optimal_params_grid['n_estimators'] = 123
```

Which works perfectly! However, when I train that model again:

```
model_xgb = XGBClassifier()
grid_search_xgb = GridSearchCV(model_xgb, optimal_params_grid, cv=5, verbose=1, n_jobs=-1)
grid_search_xgb.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set = [(X_train,y_train),(X_test,y_test)])
```

It raises this error:

```
TypeError: Parameter grid for parameter 'objective' needs to be a list or a numpy array, but got 'binary:logistic' (of type str) instead. Single values need to be wrapped in a list with one element.
```

This is because the dictionary is not in the right format. Each key should be encoded in brackets, like:

```
{'objective': ['binary:logistic'],
...
}
```

However, I can't find a way to add brackets to every value, and at the same time be 100% sure that it was done correctly. I read somewhere that when I call a dictionary (or something in a dictionary), the order is not always the same. Hence, I'm afraid of replacing the wrong value in the wrong key.

**Problems/Questions**

1. Is there any way this can be done 100% correctly?
2. As a second question, I'm wondering if there is no a more straightforward alternative to pick the latest model and modify it's number of estimators. For example, it would be nice if I could just pick the model when the estimator number 123 was trained. Is that possible? Or the only alternative is to train it again with `n_estimators=123`?

Comment: This feels like an odd use-case: grid search with cross validation should select the best hyperparameters for your target metric. (1) If it isn't, your definition of "overfitting" probably needs to be incorporated into the search. (2) If your issue can be solved by tweaking the number of trees, XGBoost supports using fewer than the maximum number of trees at prediction time with the `iteration_range` parameter (e.g. [example doc](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/examples/predict_first_ntree.html)).

Comment: Yeah, but gridsearch is very good at overfitting, because it selects the combination of hyperparameters that best performs on train. Once gridsearch select the "best performing" model, that model could be overfitting the training set, so I evaluate that in the test set while it's training, instead of just the final model. In this way, I can see the "moment" when it starts to overfit during training, so I would just select that model before the model starts to overfit.

Comment: It sounds like you're mixing up "Grid Search" (in scikit-learn: [`ParameterGrid`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ParameterGrid.html)) with "Grid Search with Cross Validation" ([`GridSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)). Cross validation already does what you're describing: splitting data, fitting on part, then evaluating on the rest.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, every time I said "GridSearch" I meant "GridSearchCV". My point is that GridSearchCV only minimizes overfitting, it doesn't assure that your model is not overfitted. So if you have GridSearchCV over 1000 n_estimators (in the XGBClassifier example) and if the model starts to overfit at estimator number 200 (plotting the metric evaluation for train and test while training), a model with n_estimator=200 will be (likely) the best model (controlling for random_state).

Comment: I agree: add `n_estimators: [50, 100, 150, ..., 1000]` to your parameter grid and evaluate which maximizes CV performance.

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, this seems to work:

```
optimal_params_grid = grid_search_xgb.best_estimator_.get_params()
optimal_params_grid['n_estimators'] = 123

# We change the format of optimal_params_grid correctly
for key, value in optimal_params_grid.items():
    optimal_params_grid[key] = [optimal_params_grid[key]]
```